# C++ pass array and its length into a function (using macro/inline function?)

Tags: c++, arrays, macros, inline

I have been writing C++ for a little while (java/C for a long while), I am wondering if there is a trick I don't know which can help me do the following.

```
vector<unsigned char> *fromArray(unsigned char data[], int length)
{
    vector<unsigned char> *ret = new vector<unsigned char >();
    while (length--)
    {
        ret->push_back(*data);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And you can use it like so:

```
unsigned char tmp[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
vector<unsigned char> *a = fromArray(tmp, sizeof(tmp));
// use `a' here
```

I find that pretty cumbersome - I'd like to write it all on one line

```
vector<unsigned char> *a = fromArray({0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
// use `a' here
```

Is such a thing possible? I don't have access to C++11 unfortunately (looks like its initializer_list is exactly what I want).

**EDIT**

Sorry I had some of the fundamentals wrong in here. I will now avoid extending std::vector. However I think the question is still valid, just that my example was a bad one.

** Potential workaround **

I *could* define a bunch of overloaded functions to take different numbers of arguments, eg

```
vector<unsigned char> *fromArray(unsigned char a)
{
    vector<unsigned char> *ret = new vector<unsigned char >();
    ret->push_back(a);
    return ret;
}

vector<unsigned char> *fromArray(unsigned char a, unsigned char b)
{
    vector<unsigned char> *ret = new vector<unsigned char >();
    ret->push_back(a);
    ret->push_back(b);
    return ret;
}
```

But I don't think I will bother...

Comment: What's wrong with `std::vector` ?

Comment: nothing :) in actual code this class extends std::vector, adds methods for printing, and convenience functions for constructing

Comment: "Methods for printing" doesn't sound like a job for extending the vector class, more like you should use non-member functions for that.

Comment: I do actually use a non member function to overload the << stream operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a template to deduce the size of any fixed size array:

```
template< class T, size_t N >
auto_ptr<ByteArray> foo( T (&data)[N] )
{
  return auto_ptr<ByteArray>(new ByteArray(data, N));
}
```

then

```
unsigned char tmp[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto_ptr<ByteArray> a = foo(tmp);
```

But bear in mind that `auto_ptr` is deprecated. Prefer `unique_ptr`. Also, note you should not publicly inherit from `std::vector`.

Comment: I will try this, thanks. As I said, I don't have access to C++11. and I don't really want to use Boost (rather, it isn't fully available on my platform).

Comment: @WayneUroda it is not designed for that. It doesn't have a virtual destructor, which means you get undefined behaviour if you are deleting an object of the derived type from a pointer to the base.

Comment: So I should not inherit from it at all, or is private inheritance safe?

Comment: @WayneUroda it is controversial. Private inheritance is almost safe, there are some pathological cases where it may cause trouble. The preferred option these days is containment. See [this article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill06.htm) for more info.

Comment: Thanks very much. I think I will change my whole approach to this.